# React setState after some seconds when user doesn't continue typing after some seconds without useReff and multiple forms

Tags: reactjs

So I'm in a situation where I can't use useReff because I have a big state where I need to edit the value directly on that state, but I also don't want the state to change and render that specific component because is to heavy and I have lag rendering the component, more exactly I'm using quill-react, and this component is big so It has so lag in input with many renders.

So I have done a function that when the user stops typing after 2 seconds a function is called, and in case it doesn't stop the function set the states to true always so the function doesn't call when is checked, but is not working for some reason, I'm kinda new on this stuff.

Here is what I have done until now, and don't forget I'm iterating a list of inputs and then managing them with setState on another component, using the method: `Work.Description`:

```
const [call, setCall] = useState(false);
    const [editors, setEditors] = useState({});
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState("");

    const handleDescription = (e: any, index: number) => {
        setCurrentIndex(index);
        setEditors( { ...editors, [index]: e } )
        setTimeout(() => setCall(true), 1000)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            if (call === true) {
                Work.Description(props, currentIndex, editors[currentIndex])
                setCurrentIndex("")
                setCall(false)
            }
        }, 1000)
    }, [])


    return (
        <Container>
            <Items>
                {
                    props.resume.employmentHistory.positions.map(
                        (position: any, index: number) => 
                                <Editor
                                    label="Description"
                                    value={position.description && position.description || ''}
                                    onChange={(e) => handleDescription(e, index)}
                                />
                    )
                }
            </Items>
        </Container >
    )
```

As I mentioned, I want something like this not that fancy with useReff or other methods, let's see what we can do.

Comment: Don't downvote for no reason, explain the reason, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce) might be what you're looking for, is that correct? Do something when user stops doing something for *n* milliseconds.

If yes then you probably don't need timeout and interval. I think you forgot to clear those timeouts/intervals by the way!

So you can do it like this (don't forget to install [@types/lodash.debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash.debounce) if you're using TypeScript):

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react'
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'

// Rename this to fit your needs.
const callWorkDescription = useCallback(
  debounce((props, currentIndex, editor) => {
    Work.Description(props, currentIndex, editor)
    setCurrentIndex("")
  }, 2000),
  []
)

const handleDescription = (e: any, index: number) => {
  setCurrentIndex(index);
  setEditors((prev) => {
    const nextEditors = { ...editors, [index]: e }
    callWorkDescription(props, index, nextEditors[index])
    return nextEditors
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes, but for example only when user stops typing after 1 sec to update the state

Comment: Oh, so if the user stops typing, both `currentIndex` and `editors` should be updated after 1 second, and `Work.Description` have to wait for 1 extra second to be called. Is that correct?

Comment: So editors need to be updated immediately but the work. the description should be called when the user stops typing after 2 seconds for example.

Comment: I see, actually that's exactly what the code in my answer does. It updates `currentIndex` and `editors` immediately, and only execute `callWorkDescription` after user stops typing for 2 seconds.

Comment: But something doesn't work with that code, can you check, for example some characters are left out, I don't know why, the last character is not included very weird

Comment: can we have a meeting?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! That's my fault, sorry about that. We should've wrapped `callWorkDescription` into a `useCallback`. I've updated my answer, you can check [this sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lny35m?file=src%2FApp.js) for a simple example.

Comment: Thank you, wirdely is misin the last character on the update, also doesn't update for example when I select and delete, I need something when stops typing, wait 2 seconds and update the last state from editor state, not something more fancy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247327/discussion-between-nevoni3008-and-abemscac).

Comment: this deserves to be chosen 20 times as correct, but one is the limit

Comment: Hi there, my friend! I hope you still remember me; it's been a while since we last communicated. I'm not sure if you're still working with React or doing any frontend development, but if you are, I wanted to let you know that I published a free documentation that might be helpful in improving your understanding of React. You can read it here: https://piesdoc.com/